# How to persist an object which has nested list of objects

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a task list application, in Java, in which the tasks can have dependent tasks.  So, the task class looks like this:

```
public class Task implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5372927338757312018L;
private long id;
private String title;
private String description;
private Task parent;
private Set<Task> children;
```

The tasks are persisted to postgres.  Currently, there are 2 tables:

**tasks table**: id, title, description
**parent_child table**: parent_id, child_id

To deserialize, I retrieve the task in question, construct the object, then I retrieve each of the dependent/child tasks, construct them, and add them to the original task as children.  The challenge is each child task can have its own dependent/child tasks.

Retrieve the task (and whether it has any children):

```
SELECT id, title, description, start, due, totalhours, completedhours,

(SELECT 
  COUNT(*)
  FROM todo.parent_child 
  WHERE todo.parent_child.parent_id = '201'
  ) AS child_count

FROM todo.tasks 
WHERE id = '201'
GROUP BY id, title, description, start, due, totalhours, completedhours;
```

If the child_count is greater than 0, I follow up with additional queries to retrieve the dependent/child tasks.

This is all doable as is, but is there a better approach to modeling and/or persisting the tasks?  More generally, how should objects, with nested lists of objects, be persisted and reconstructed?

Comment: Not sure about the down vote, since no comments were added.  If there is something I can do to improve the question, please let me know.

Comment: You could use some ORM like Hibernate to do the persistence job. If you cant/dont want to use such framework, you could call the load task method recursively for each task in the list.

Comment: Thanks Michal, looks like ORM is the answer.  I'm new to the data side, so this opens up a lot of options (and answers my question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment, you can use some ORM like Hibernate. In the other case you can write recursive method like this:

```
Task loadTaskWithChildren(long taskId) {
  Task task = loadSingleTaskFromDb(taskId);
  for(long childId : getChildrenIds(taskId))
    task.addChild(loadTaskWithChildren(childId);
}
```